# How can I split string of numbers to array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have `string s = "4 99 34 56 28";`

I need to split this string to the array: `[4, 99, 34, 56, 28]`

I do it in java:

```
String line = reader.readLine();
String[] digits = line.split(" ");
```

But how can I do it in C++? without external libraries.

Comment: "But how can I do it in C++? without external libraries." using a loop obviously.

Comment: @ Slava I am new in C++. Can You share some example?

Answer (score 1):

[Split the string by spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-words-of-a-string), and for every token (number in your case), convert the string to an int, like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // stoi

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    string s("4 99 34 56 28");
    string buf;      
    stringstream ss(s); 

    vector<int> tokens;

    while (ss >> buf)
        tokens.push_back(stoi(buf));

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i)
      cout << tokens[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4
99
34
56
28
```

Comment: why `stoi` and not directly `operator >> (istream&, int&)` ?

Comment: Was ``sstream`` not the buggy one and ``stringstream`` the header everyone should use? It has been a while (years), since I remembered "use the longer of the 2".

Comment: OP is a "newbie", so I think my MCVE is more natural and readable that way.

Comment: this code fails on line `tokens.push_back(stoi(buf));`

Comment: `[Error] 'stoi' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: @ip696 I forgot to include the `string` library of STL, answer updated, now it should be working. Check it out and tell me! :D